# Reassign the multiple column's value from other rows in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Got a `dataframe`, CY (current year)- refers to 2022, PY (Previous Year) - refers to 2021, & PPY (Prior to Previous year) refers to 2020. Want to collect this information as in a single row for a single id. Input dataframe looks like -

```
id  Year    Jan_CY  Feb_CY  Jan_PY  Feb_PY  Jan_PPY Feb_PPY
1   2022    1   2   0   0   0   0
1   2021    0   0   3   4   0   0
1   2020    0   0   0   0   5   6
2   2022    0   0   0   0   0   0
2   2021    0   0   7   8   0   0
2   2020    0   0   0   0   9   10
```

Output dataframe looks like

```
id  Year    Jan_CY  Feb_CY  Jan_PY  Feb_PY  Jan_PPY Feb_PPY
0   1   2022    1   2   3   4   5   6
1   2   2022    0   0   7   8   9   10
```

Tried with below code:

```
def get_previous_values(row):
    
    cols = row.columns
    py_cols = [i for i in cols if i.endswith("_PY")]
    ppy_cols = [j for j in cols if j.endswith("_PPY")]
    row[py_cols].mask((df['clnt_orgn_id'] == clnt_orgn_id) & (df['SMRY_YR_NO'] == 2021), df[py_cols])
    return row
```

but couldn't solve it.

Answer (score 0):

If the result is just the column sum, then a groupby would do it:

```
df.groupby("id").sum()
```

Note: This requires every year to appear exactly one time for each ID.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
curr_year = 2022
years = {curr_year: 'CY', curr_year-1: 'PY', curr_year-2: 'PPY'}

# or directly
# years = {2022: 'CY', 2021: 'PY', 2020: 'PPY'}

out = (df
   .rename(columns=lambda x: x.split('_')[0])
   .pivot(index='id', columns='Year')
   .sort_index(axis=1, level=1, ascending=False)
   .groupby(axis=1, level=[0, 1], sort=False).sum()
   .pipe(lambda d: d.set_axis(d.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}_{years[x[1]]}'), axis=1))
   .reset_index()
)
# optionally add the current year
out.insert(1, 'Year', curr_year)

print(out)
```

Output:

```
   id  Year  Jan_CY  Feb_CY  Jan_PY  Feb_PY  Jan_PPY  Feb_PPY
0   1  2022       1       2       3       4        5        6
1   2  2022       0       0       7       8        9       10
```